# Sending 2 parameter when rendering a view in Yii

Tags: yii

I have a action in testController with **view** name. In this view I render another controller's view:

```
$this->render('/page/view', array('model' => 'Page'));
```

I need to when render , send 2 parameter

Like this: `http://localhsot/test/controller/view/1/age/25` or anything...

When I use `$this->render('/page/view', array('model' => 'Page', 'age' => '25'));`
 I get error.

Comment: @ethrbunny My mistake was in use as $_GET method, I had to use $age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it:

```
$this->render('/page/view', array('model' => 'Page', 'age' => '25'));
```

and in view:

```
echo $age;
```